# ios Firebase - segue data in a "details post" Controller

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

Here is my situation:

I have a controller "Feed" which list multiple posts via a table ( a title and image) from Firebase.

[image]

On touch of a button, it bring to a "Feed Details" controller, where I would like the data ( title image and caption) from the post clicked previously (parent) being display. ( see screenshot 2)

[image]

At the moment nothing is being fetch when I arrive to the feed details controllers ...

How is it possible to fetch the details from the item click previously ??

Currently this is my feed controller:

```
 //
//  FeedVC.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,      UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var addImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleInputView: InputTextView!

@IBOutlet weak var captionInputView: InputTextView!


private var posts = [Post]()
private var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
private var imageSelected = false

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    feedTableView.dataSource = self

    feedTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    feedTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 320

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED))
    {
        posts in

        self.posts = posts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell
    {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(tableView: tableView, post: post)
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        fatalError()
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        addImageView.image = image
        imageSelected = true
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func selectImagePressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    guard let caption = captionInputView.text, !caption.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: Caption must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let title = titleInputView.text, !title.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: title must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let image = addImageView.image, imageSelected else
    {
        print("POST: Image must be selected")
        return
    }

    guard let currentUserId = User.currentUserId else
    {
        print("POST: Can't post before logging in")
        return
    }

    imageSelected = false
    addImageView.image = UIImage(named: "add-image")
    captionInputView.text = nil
    titleInputView.text = nil

    // Uploads the image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)
    {
        let imageUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imageUid).put(imageData, metadata: metadata)
        {
            (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Failed to upload image to storage \(error)")
            }

            if let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            {
                // Caches the image for faster display
                Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: downloadURL as NSString)

                print("STORAGE: Successfully uploaded image to storage")
                _ = Post.post(caption: caption, title: title, imageUrl: downloadURL, creatorId: currentUserId)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Doesn't listen to posts anymore
    readPosts?.stop()

    try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    User.currentUserId = nil
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

I'm using the code for the feeddetails - Which of course doesn't feet the data

My database structure look like below:

[image]

How is it possible to fetch the data in that details view ?? If anybody could explain me the process, it will be really fantastic !!

Thank you for all your time and help !!

----- EDIT: --------

Thanks to Retterdesdialogs, I've update the code and the App start, but when i click on the button linkbutton nothin happen and the App crash:

The Console display:
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1087f6758) to 'MobileAppDemo.FeedDetailsController' (0x104bc34a0).

I'm having now for code:

feedVC.swift ( there all the post are listed):

```
 //
 //  FeedVC.swift
 //  MobileAppDemo
 //
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

 import UIKit
 import FirebaseAuth
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseStorage
 import SwiftKeychainWrapper
 import SwiftyJSON

  class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
 @IBOutlet weak var addImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleInputView: InputTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var captionInputView: InputTextView!


private var posts = [Post]()
private var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
private var imageSelected = false

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    feedTableView.dataSource = self

    feedTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    feedTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 320

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED))
    {
        posts in

        self.posts = posts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }



}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


// here you need to add
{


    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell
    {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(tableView: tableView, post: post)
        cell.linkbutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.linkbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedVC.toFeedDetailAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        fatalError()
    }
}

func toFeedDetailAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let FeedDetailsController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedDetailsIdentifier") as! FeedDetailsController
    FeedDetailsController.post = posts[sender.tag]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FeedDetailsController, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        addImageView.image = image
        imageSelected = true
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func selectImagePressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    guard let caption = captionInputView.text, !caption.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: Caption must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let title = titleInputView.text, !title.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: title must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let image = addImageView.image, imageSelected else
    {
        print("POST: Image must be selected")
        return
    }

    guard let currentUserId = User.currentUserId else
    {
        print("POST: Can't post before logging in")
        return
    }

    imageSelected = false
    addImageView.image = UIImage(named: "add-image")
    captionInputView.text = nil
    titleInputView.text = nil

    // Uploads the image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)
    {
        let imageUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imageUid).put(imageData, metadata: metadata)
        {
            (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Failed to upload image to storage \(error)")
            }

            if let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            {
                // Caches the image for faster display
                Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: downloadURL as NSString)

                print("STORAGE: Successfully uploaded image to storage")
                _ = Post.post(caption: caption, title: title, imageUrl: downloadURL, creatorId: currentUserId)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Doesn't listen to posts anymore
    readPosts?.stop()

    try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    User.currentUserId = nil
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
 }
```

and the FeedDetails.swift ( where the Detail are listed once you have clicked the button, button has class: linkbutton from the viewVC Controller:

```
  //
 //  FeedDetailsController.swift
 //  MobileAppDemo
 //
 //  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 27.10.2016.
 //  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
 //

 import UIKit
 import FBSDKCoreKit
 import FBSDKLoginKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseAuth
 import SwiftKeychainWrapper



 fileprivate struct RegisterInfo
 {
 let email: String
 let password: String
 }


 class FeedDetailsController: UIViewController
 {
 @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var post: Post!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    if User.currentUserId != nil
    {
        print("AUTH: USING EXISTING KEYCHAIN")
        User.startTrackingCurrentUser()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("AUTH: NO EXSTING KEYCHAIN")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    print("AUTH: Preparing for segue \(segue.identifier)")

    if let registrationVC = segue.destination as? RegisterVC
    {
        print("AUTH: Found registration VC")

        if let info = sender as? RegisterInfo
        {
            print("AUTH: Sending email (\(info.email)) and password (\(info.password.characters.count) chars) information: ")
            registrationVC.setBaseInfo(email: info.email, password: info.password)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signInButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
        {
            (user, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                // TODO: Handle other errors here as well
                switch FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code)!
                {
                case .errorCodeUserNotFound:
                    print("AUTH: USER NOT FOUND -> CREATING NEW USER")
                    print("AUTH: Sending email \(email) and password \(password.characters.count) characters")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterUser", sender: RegisterInfo(email: email, password: password))
                default: print("AUTH: ERROR IN EMAIL LOGIN \(error)") // TODO: Inform user
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("AUTH: EMAIL AUTH SUCCESSFUL")
                User.currentUserId = user?.uid
                User.startTrackingCurrentUser()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    // TODO: Inform user that the field contents are missing
}

@IBAction func facebookButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    // (Already logged in to FB)
    if let fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    {
        print("AUTH: Already logged in to FB")
        firebaseAuth(with: FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: fbAccessToken.tokenString))
    }
    else
    {
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
        facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self)
        {
            (result, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("AUTH: UNABLE TO AUTHENTICATE WITH FACEBOOK")
                print("AUTH: \(error)")
            }
            else if let result = result
            {
                if result.isCancelled
                {
                    print("AUTH: USER CANCELLED FACEBOOK AUTH")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("AUTH: FACEBOOK AUTH SUCCESS")
                    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
                    self.firebaseAuth(with: credential)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func firebaseAuth(with credential: FIRAuthCredential)
{
    if FIRAuth.auth() == nil
    {
        print("AUTH: NO AUTH SERVICE AVAILABLE")
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential)
    {
        (user, error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            print("AUTH: UNABLE TO AUTHENTICATE TO FIREBASE")
            print("AUTH: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            if let user = user
            {
                print("AUTH: SUCCESSFULLY AUTHENTICATED WITH FIREBASE")

                // Updates current user data
                var userName = "User"
                var image: UIImage?

                if let retrievedName = user.displayName
                {
                    userName = retrievedName
                }
                if let retrievedImageUrl = user.photoURL
                {
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: retrievedImageUrl)
                    {
                        image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }

                User.post(uid: user.uid, provider: user.providerID, userName: userName, image: image)
                {
                    user in

                    User.currentUser = user
                    User.startTrackingCurrentUser()

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to be able to access the button through IBOutlet or programmatically

2) set the button to the cells indexPath.row and add an action to it

```
let post = posts[indexPath.row]
cell.configureCell(tableView: tableView, post: post)
// here you need to add
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedViewController.toFeedDetailAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
return cell
```

3) when you then press the button you can identify your feed, because you have the button tag, so you know the feed from your Posts-Array

```
func toFeedDetailAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let feedDetailsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedDetailsIdentifier") as! FeedDetailsViewController
    feedDetailsViewController.post = posts[sender.tag]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(feedDetailsViewController, animated: true)  
}
```

4) in your FeedDetailsViewController add

```
var post: Post!
```

5) in FeedDetailsViewController do what ever you want with the post

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Terrerdesdialogs, THanks for your time I really appreciate !

1/ is it ok in my feedVC.swift to add     @IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!
 like that ? linkbutton being the class of the button

2/ where do i put this code ? still in the feedVC.swift ? which part of the code above ?

Thanks a lot, im just starting with Xcode and iOS :) :)

Comment: edit:

while adding   cell.linkbutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.linkbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedViewController.toFeedDetailAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell

i get 'Value of type 'MessageCell' has no member 'linkbutton' 

I don't manage to get it fix :(

Comment: edit 3 ,

ok i have fixed 1 and 2

in 3/ I'm having this error: Value of type 'FeedDetailsController.post has no member post ? 

i have put var post: Post! in my FeedDetailsController so i don't really understand why ??

Comment: edit 4: ok, i've moved the car post: Post! in the UIVIewController class, now the App start, but after few seconds I m having in my feedvc.swift an eroor in the line:

            cell.linkbutton.tag = indexPath.row


Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

If anybody have an idea ?? Thanks :) :)

Comment: Hi, sorry i don't know what the problem is. Your cell in feedVC should have the button "linkbutton" so you can access it with cell.linkbutton. I can't help you if you not providing the new code.